# What's the Difference between StringTokenizer and java.util.Scanner Class

Tags: java

I have a question regarding the Difference between `StringTokenizer` class and `java.util.Scanner` class? Though both are used for Dissection (tokenization) purpose. Which one is better to use and have better efficiency? Are these two java classes are alternatives for each other or have separate purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `JavaDoc`:

> **StringTokenizer** is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of String
>   or the `java.util.regex` package instead.

Comment: As i stated in my answer String.split is rather slow concerning high load applications. StringUtils.split is way faster.

Comment: I think split method of java.util.regex.Pattern Class will be more better than the two

Comment: It's just about 10x slower than StringUtils.split.

Comment: @Naeem : String.split just uses the Pattern.split method, so it can't be better than the two. StringUtils.split is much faster because it doesn't use a regex. BTW, they changed the implementation in Java 7 to avoid using a regex when the pattern argument is simple and thus doesn't need one.

Answer (score 2):

From StringTokenizer javadoc

> The string tokenizer class allows an application to break a string
>   into token.... The StringTokenizer methods do not distinguish among
>   identifiers, numbers, and quoted strings...

From Scanner javadoc

> A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings
>   using regular expressions.

So Scanner unlike StringTokenizer have methods like nextInt, nextBoolean etc. 
While Scanner is usefull in some cases when you need to parse user input containig numbers, StringTokenizer in most cases can be replaced with org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.split - which doesn't use regular expressions and is pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

One big difference is that a Scanner can operate on input streams, so you do not need to have it in memory all at once (which in some cases is not even possible, for example when continuously reading user input from a console).